# Can I submit a new app version to apple without cancelling a pending release?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, ios

I have an app Pending Release and would like to update it with a newer version that includes some minor bugs fixes.

Can I do so without removing the App pending release? I don't want to risk that we receive green light to go live and the new app is stuck pending Apple review.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll need to cancel the current pending release, upload the new app, go thru the Review process again, and then you can release it.

This way Apple, and the users, can be sure that developers are not putting malware or viruses in code that's already been reviewed and approved for release.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will do a live update bypassing Apple then. Can't risk that the app remains stuck in review for 2 weeks (as it happened before).
I don't see how it's a security risk to be able to have at the same time 2 apps approved and waiting for release (eg. v1.2.1 and v1.2.2) and then I decide which one should go live. Would be a nice feature :)
Thx again

Comment: FYI, in the past (like over a year ago) I had several-week delays in reviews.  Now, they're pretty good at getting them done in a day or two.  You can always do the update via Testflight first and get a prelim review.  That might make the final review go quicker.

Comment: I submitted it three weeks ago and it was just an update. It took them 2 weeks. I had a metadata rejection though - wrong device in the attached image for one of the resolutions. Just to start looking at it it took them 10 days.

Comment: That's pretty bad.  Average review times are down to 1 day.  If it takes more than 2 days you should contact the app review team.